# I can´t use the face tracker with the back camera in android

Tags: arcore, tracker, face

I create a game to add filter and 3d object in real time, but I can´t configure the back camera to face tracker, for example I need add 3d object in a people with the back camere, and this have to detect the rotation or move. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

AugmentedFaces API works only with front camera. 
You can check out [shared camera access](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/camera-sharing) documentation and see if you can combine ARCore with [Face Detection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces) from Firebase or OpenCV

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. It's clearly asking for an ability to track faces using rear/back camera and add augmentation on faces.

Answer (score 0):

Been trying to do this for a while now and I succeeded using the combination of MLKit Face Detection (Open-sourced by Google) and Sceneform/Rajawali.

I can track multiple faces via rear camera and get its size, rotation etc and produce/render 3D models over them using sceneform or Rajawali.

Wont be easy tho but worth a try.